# nested array in strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-6

I have inputs which get loaded over ajax and get's inserted in a other form with javascript with this fields:

```
<input name="project[config][service][3][web][auth]" type="checkbox">
```

and two other inputs with:

```
<input type="text" name="project[config][service][3][web][user]">
<input type="text" name="project[config][service][3][web][pass]">
```

how can I permit this to the controller to accept the values?

I tried it with these:

```
params.require(:project).permit(
        :title,
        :description,
        config: [
            service: {
                [] => [
                    :domains,
                    web: [
                        :auth,
                        :user,
                        :pass
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ],
        documents: []
      )
```

but it didn't worked.
In the console i have this as `project_params[:config]`

```
{"service"=><ActionController::Parameters {"3"=><ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>} permitted: true>}
```

the `params[:project][:config]` looks like this:

```
{
  "service" => { 
    "3" => {
      "web" => {
        "auth"=>"on",
        "user"=>"asdasdasdasda",
        "pass"=>"asdasdasd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way, it should work:

```
params.require(:project).permit(
       :title, 
       :description, 
       config: {
         service: [
           :domains,
           web: [:auth, :user, :pass]
         ]
       },
       documents: []
     )
```

Comment: yes, thanks! But can you explain why or whats wrong with my? :)

Comment: @Evolutio problem is on the part of `service: { [] => [` definition. The hash you've added when the key is an empty array. You don't have to do that. Rails recognise an `array` by numbers in the keys and do the array processing for you.